# JSON string selected from database ends up in wrong format when encoding JSON in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

I have a database where there are a couple of simple text columns, and one column, which hosts a JSON string with additional data.

I have a PHP script which selects data in this database, and encodes the results in JSON, and sends it back to my C# application, where I deserialize the JSON string into a custom object.

Everything was fine, until I recently added the JSON string column to the database, and my C# deserializer (Newtonsoft) fails to deserialize that column into the C# object it should be converted to.

Here's how the JSON result gets back into C# (before deserializing):

```
{
 "Status":"OK",
 "Result":
   [
    {
      "Name":"This is a name",
      "Address":"This is an address",
      "CustomData":"[{\"CustomDataName\":\"Name\",\"CustomDataLabel\":\"Data Label\",\"CustomDataValue\":\"Some random value\",\"CustomDataType\":\"Text\",\"Permission\":\"1\"},{\"CustomDataName\":\"Something random\",\"CustomDataLabel\":\"\",\"CustomDataValue\":\"Value goes here\",\"CustomDataType\":\"Text\",\"Permission\":\"1\"}]  
    }
   ],
 "GeneralErrorMessage":""
}
```

The CustomData property of this JSON should be converted into a **CustomDataClass** objectin C# which has the CustomDataName, CustomDataLabel, CustomDataType, CustomDataValue, Permission properties.

However, you can see that there are backslashes in the string, which suggest, that I'm not selecting it correctly from the database, or I'm not encoding/decoding in the right way.

C# part:

```
//reading the response from the PHP script...
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        jsonresponse += reader.ReadLine();
    }
}

//converting the string response from the PHP script to our object
JSONResponseClass jrt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONResponseClass>(jsonresponse);
//fails on this line ^
```

JSONResponseClass looks like this:

```
public class JSONResponseClass 
{
    public String Status;

    public List<myObject> Result;

    public String GeneralErrorMessage;
}
```

myObject class looks like this:

```
public class myObject
{
    public String Name;

    public String Address;

    public List<CustomDataClass> CustomData;
}
```

Error message in C# when trying to deserialize:

> Error converting value "[{"CustomDataName":"asdasdasdas","CustomDataLabel":"asdasdasdas","CustomDataValue":"RandomValue...","CustomDataType":"Text","Permission":"1"},...]" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[NameSpace.myObject]'. Path 'Result[0].CustomData', line 1, position 2167.

PHP part (database selection, and JSON encoding:

```
$returnedSelection = SelectValuesFromDatabase(); //get the values from the database

$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->Status = "OK";
$obj->Result = $returnedSelection;
$obj->GeneralErrorMessage = "";
die(json_encode($obj));

function SelectValuesFromDatabase()
{
    $con = SetupConnector();
    $ResultArray = array(); //return values will be stored in this array

    $sql = "SELECT name as Name, address as Address, jsondata as CustomData FROM data_table";

    if($result=mysqli_query($con, $sql))
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $ResultArray[] = $row;
        }   
    }
    return $ResultArray;
}
```

What is the necessary step to do, in order to get a the right CustomData value into the JSON that is coming from the PHP?

Comment: What is the origin of the JSON string (with escaped quotes in some places), who generated it and then who is consuming it?

Comment: The same application is inserting it in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in image your json is not valid and you encode "CustomData" and then you encode second time in your final object. If you remove first encoding operation everything will be fine.[image]

Your CustomData field is already a json. So you should decode first. 
You need to change your php code with followings.

```
$returnedSelection = SelectValuesFromDatabase(); //get the values from the database

$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->Status = "OK";
$obj->Result = $returnedSelection;
$obj->GeneralErrorMessage = "";
die(json_encode($obj));

function SelectValuesFromDatabase()
{
    $con = SetupConnector();
    $ResultArray = array(); //return values will be stored in this array

    $sql = "SELECT name as Name, address as Address, jsondata as CustomData FROM data_table";

    if($result=mysqli_query($con, $sql))
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $row[2] = json_decode($row[2]);
            $ResultArray[] = $row;
        }   
    }
    return $ResultArray;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I ended up doing this. Thank you very much